# Scrolling ion-content is scrolling header and tabs wrongly

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

When I scroll the page, it scroll the header too when it is on beginning of the page. And it scroll the tabs when I click on tab and scroll it.

I recorded the problem: https://youtu.be/GNJtqy9ZrDE

I already try some stuffs, like add css "overflow-y: hidden", I searched the problem but I couldn't find any solution.

I don't have any css modifying this ion-content or something else, only the default ionic 3 application.

```
"ionic": "^5.2.3",
"ionic-angular": "3.9.5",
"cordova-ios": "^5.0.1",
```

```html
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar color="primary">
    <ion-title>Leilões</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>

  <!--MY CONTENT-->

</ion-content>
```

I have this exact same problem in other app, and I couldn't find solution too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this line to your config.xml and then do a clean build and it should work as expected

```
<preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true"/>
```

[Reference](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/config_ref/index.html#preference)